# How to re-indent nginx configuration based only on `{` and `}`?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, indent

I want to reindent an `nginx` configuration file with the following simple rudimentary rules:

- a `{`  increases indentation
- a `}` decreases indentation

The idea is `cindent` is just enough to do it. I have the following file:

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}
```

I run `vim -u NONE ./thefile.conf` and type **`gg=G`** to apply `=` as an re-indenting operator to the whole file and vim indents the whole file by aligning the data below `*` to the same column:

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
                                  events {
                                  worker_connections 1024;
                                  }
```

On the other hand, if I remove the `*` star character from the first line, doing `=` operator on the whole file re-indents the whole file just fine:

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

Removing star characters from the file fixes it - I can indent big files that way. How to tell vim `=` command not to increase indentation on `*` character when re-indenting the file? Why does `*` character break the indentation when using the `=` command?

Also, only `/*` breaks the indentation. Doing `/  *` or `/something*` does not break it and indentation seem to work fine. Why? I tried to test other characters like `&` `^` instead of `*`, and they didn't have the same effect as `*`.

Comment: Presumably because `/*` is the beginning of a comment in some languages. What file types are affected the way you describe?

Comment: Suggested reading `:h format-comments`. It suggests that `indentexpr` may be better than `cindent` at dealing with three piece comments (which `/*` is part of, i.e. the first piece). `'fo'` may also be involved here. What do you have for that setting?

Comment: Oooooch, right, how didn't I think of that.... The filetype is not set, it's empty, normal vim detects `ft=conf`. I will try `:set comments=` to something simple, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Matt notes, `smartindent` is enough. Not only this, but `cindent` is actively harmful!

Many years ago, when I first got started with vim, I had these both set globally in my vimrc. Eventually, through spurious indenting issues such as these, I came to realize that in fact they make *bad* global settings. `cindent` is too specific; it works for C stuff. Don't set that globally. And `smartindent` is better, but for C-like programs! (Basically, around braces, and some hacks with `cinwords`.)

In the end, it is better to *remove* these local indent options from your global config, and relegate them to filetype-specific areas (e.g., ftplugins).

On the other hand, `autoindent` is a fine global indent option, as it often does what you want and stays out of the way when other options are set.

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my default/global config. Just `'ai'`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need in `cindent`, as `smartindent` should be enough. So simply:

```
setlocal smartindent cinwords=
```

Comment: Well, so I did `set smartindent cindent cinwords=` and copied my file into empty file with unset `filetype` and got same result. Is `lisp` indenting kicking in then? The problem is `smartindent` works _when you type_ - ie. I type `{` and it indents next line - this is great! But I want to __re-indent__ (with `=`) an existing file - `smartindent` is not for that. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @KamilCuk Have you read `:h =`? Smartindent is not about it. If you believe you need "equal" too you can write indentexpr of your own.